# Can I restrict the NSMutableArray object type?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I want the NSMutableArray only store "MyObject" only... ...instead of any objects. How can I do this? thz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concept like C# Generics or C++ Templates in Objective-C, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848641/are-there-strongly-typed-collections-in-objective-c) before, but you could create a class which exposes an array and has add and remove-methods which take only your object type (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793644/is-there-anything-like-a-generic-list-in-cocoa-objective-c)).