# Type specifier for NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am trying to declare a NSMutableArray to use to hold some `Contact` objects. I am following the instructions given in this question,  [how and where do I initialize an global NSMutableArray in Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995395/how-and-where-do-i-intialize-an-global-nsmutablearray-in-xcode-5). But have left off the `@synthesize` because according to this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C_2.0) it says that it is implicit in newer versions of xcode. I have also tried including it and get the same errors so I don't think it is the problem but I just thought I would mention it.

I am getting these errors[image: errors] but can't figure out what exactly they mean because according to these questions:
[Type of class in a NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093360/type-of-class-in-a-nsmutablearray)
[Can I restrict the NSMutableArray object type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690821/can-i-restrict-the-nsmutablearray-object-type)
[Is there any way to enforce typing on NSArray, NSMutableArray, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649483/is-there-any-way-to-enforce-typing-on-nsarray-nsmutablearray-etc)

NSMutableArrays do not enforce the types of objects that are placed into them.

What am I doing wrong and what do these errors mean? This is my first Objective C project and I believe this is a simple problem but nevertheless it is one that I have not been able to figure out and has been frustrating me for hours.

Here is my header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Contact.h"

@interface ContactList : NSObject

@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *contactList;

+ (BOOL) addContact: (Contact *) contact;
- (BOOL) emptyContactList;
//- (BOOL) buildContactList

@end
```

and here is my implementation file:

```
#import "ContactList.h"

@implementation ContactList

contactList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

+ (BOOL) addContact: (Contact *) contact
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL) emptyContactList
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: You have to assign contactList in a method. ie. init

Comment: The assignment must be inside a method, and, to avoid ambiguity, at least, you should precede it with `self.`.

Comment: You made addContact a class method. Are you really, really sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add onto the already correct answers, if the array needs to exist as part of the initialization of the class, you can include it's setup in an init method as:

```
-(instancetype) init{
     self = [super init];
     if(self){
         _contactList = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     }
     return self;
 }
```

Just be aware that you can't set up instance variables in a class method. Meaning, you would only be able to call your `+addContact:` method *after* you created an instance of your `ContactList` class. Otherwise the array would always be nil, regardlesss of how many `Contact`s you added

[This resource](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/classes#constructor-methods) may provide you with some additional insight on class constructors

Answer (score 1):

When referecing your property anyway I believe self needs to be in front, as in `self.contactList`

However to initialize you should do lazy instantiation by overwriting the "getter" for your property in your implementation file.

I believe it will be

```
// The getter method for property "contactList"
-(NSMutableArray *)contactList {
    // If no array exists, create one.
    if (!_contactList) {
        _contactList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]
    }
return _contactList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok. It looks like you have a class `ContactList` that contains a property `contactList`, where `contactList` is a mutable array.

I never liked using the same words with different case to mean different things, so I would change the name of the property.

Using a class name with a capital letter (e.g. `ContactList`) and an instance variable in lower case (`contactList`) is something I've seen a fair amount. (But I don't like that either. It leads to confusion later.)

That's just my opinion though.

You have a line of executable code in your @implementation... @end block that is not inside any method or function:

```
contactList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You can't do that. All executable code must be inside a method or function somewhere. That's what the compiler is telling you.

You should probably define a custom init method for your class, as described by @LouisTur in his answer.

Comment: What's with the "drive-by" down vote? IF you disagree with my post, say why.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this file was trying to declare a global variable named "contactList" and set it.

However, when declared outside a method or @interface, a variable must by typed, much like a C global.  If you want to create such a global, try the following.  (Note that this will usually cause a memory leak message at runtime in the console due to alloc/init being called before Objective-C is fully set up.)

```
static NSMutableArray* contactList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

To use a more Objective-C solution, declare the static and set it to nil, (gives no message) then set it in the +initialize method. (Google for +initialize to see many good explanations of how it is guaranteed by Objective-C to be called only once.)

```
static NSMutableArray* contactList = nil;

+ (void) initialize {
    contactList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

(Naming conventions for static global variables I'll leave for another conversation.)

Comment: Fails if there is ever more than one ContactList object.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, it would fail if ContactList was a normal instance object, but the question shows a global variable and a class method to add contacts, so it is easy to conclude the asker is using a singleton pattern. So, there is never more than one ContactList object.