# NSMutableArray with only a particular type of objects

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

is it possible to specify that a NSMutableArray can only contain a certain type of objects.
For example, if I want to store only this kind of objects :

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    UInt8 value; 
}
```

In order to be able to use the instance variable like this :

```
- (void)myMethod:(NSMutableArray *)myArray{
    for (id myObject in myArray){
        [self otherMethod:myObject.value];
    }
}
```

because I'm getting this error :

```
request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting that error, because for as far as Objective-C is concerned, `myObject` is of the non-type `id`, which doesn't support the `value` property. To make Objective-C aware of the fact it's always dealing with a `MyObject` in this loop, you'll have to tell it the `myObject` object is an instance of `MyObject`.

```
for (MyObject *myObject in myArray) {
```

Also, you have to make sure the `value` ivar is accessible using dot-notation by implementing getter and setter methods for it. You can do this yourself by implementing `-value` and `-setValue:`, or you can use `@property` and `@synthesize` to let Objective-C do this.

Answer (score 15):

It sounds like you're coming from a Java/C# type background where limits can be imposed on collections.

Collections in Cocoa don't follow that pattern. There is no way to set a restriction on what type of objects can be inserted (unless you write a wrapper class that enforces this).

Objective-C, by design, follows the "if it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it most probably is a duck" philosophy. That is to say that rather than checking whether an object is a particular type, you should be checking whether it can do what you want it to do regardless of its type.

You can do this using `respondsToSelector:`.

Finally, your problem isn't actually related to the fact that the array has no restrictions. Your object doesn't appear to declare the instance variable `value` as a property, or expose any accessor methods for it.

This is why you're seeing the error when you try `myObject.value`. That syntax in Objective-C is how you access properties.

The default scope for instance variables in Objective-C is `@protected`, which means anything outside your class can't access them without going through an accessor method of some kind.

You need to declare and define the methods `- (UInt8)value` and `- (void)setValue:(UInt8)aValue` and use them.

Alternatively, you could declare it as a property.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C doesn't work like that. You need to use `[myObject value]` (which will work irrespective of the kind of object, as long as it responds to `-[value]`. If you only want one type of objects in it, insert only that type of objects.

Comment: [myObject value] wasn't working... because there were other choices for this method... I renamed my instance variable in "myValue" and now [myObject myValue] works..

Comment: Introduced in Objective-C 2, you can also use dot-notation to access properties, or any method that doesn't require arguments, really. So `myObject.value` is perfectly good syntax-wise.

Comment: only if the compiler knows the receiver type, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a wrapper-class for the `NSMutableArray`, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793644/is-there-anything-like-a-generic-list-in-cocoa-objective-c).

Comment: Thank you for for the link, I might need to use it soon. Good to know

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `NSMutableArray` and override methods that mediate the addition of objects to the array. You would check the object type in these overridden methods, only calling `[super addObject:xyz]` if the type is accepted.

Comment: This is a *bad* idea. `NSMutableArray` is an abstract class, you can't really subclass it without writing your own implementation of an array.

Comment: Rather than subclass, create a wrapper. The wrapper class can contain a private instance of an NSArray and expose an interface that allows you to do the type checking.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use protocol:

```
@protocol Person <NSObject>
@end

@interface Person : NSObject <Person>
@end
```

to use:

```
NSArray<Person>*  personArray;
```