# Missing sentinel in method dispatch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, subclass

I want to create a subclass of `NSMutableArray` and need to override the `-initWithObjects:` method.

But How to call [super xxx];?

```
- (id) initWithObjects:(id)firstObj, ... {
    [super initWithObjects:firstObj]; // Error: Missing sentinel in method dispatch
    // Error: The result of a delegate init call must be immediately returned or assigned to "self"

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. As discussed in [the documentation for `NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

> You might want to implement an initializer for your subclass that is
>   suited to the backing store that the subclass is managing. The NSArray
>   class does not have a designated initializer, so your initializer need
>   only invoke the `init` method of `super`. The NSArray class adopts the
>   NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, and NSCoding protocols; if you want
>   instances of your own custom subclass created from copying or coding,
>   override the methods in these protocols.

So you can assign `self = [super init];` and add the objects from your initialiser to the resulting object. Indeed, because of the way that `NSArray` is implemented, calling any `-initWith…` method is likely to return an instance of a *different* `NSArray` subclass.

Notice that the documentation also discusses alternatives to subclassing `NSArray` that may be easier, more reliable or better in some other way.

Answer (score 47):

Then "missing sentinel" message refers to the missing nil termination. In fact, according to font-of-all-knowledge-Wikipedia:

The name of the nil that terminates a variable length list of parameters in Objective-C

also: Sentinel node, an object to represent the end of a data structure
also: Sentinel value, a value used to terminate a loop
also: In network protocols such as Bisync, sentinel values indicate where frames start and end

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` doesn't work like subclassing most classes. `NSArray` is a class cluster, please see [subclassing notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-740795) from the `NSArray` documentation.

Now, for your specific question, subclassing `va_list` methods is a bit tricky, there are a number of ways to handle this. The 'safest' would be to process your `va_list` into an `NSArray` and pass that into another method that dealt with whatever you wanted. The other, slightly less portable, slightly hackier way is to create a new `va_list` list on the stack to pass through.

```
    id __unsafe_unretained * stack = (typeof(stack))calloc(numOfObjects, sizeof(id));
    //filloutStack
    [super initWithObjects:*stack, nil];
    free(stack);
```

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing Apples Collection classes isn't that difficult — if you use a tiny trick (see also: [cocoawithlove](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html)).

A subclass is a "is-a" relationship in object-orientated Design. But there are also "has-a" relationships, i.e. wrappers.

If you would try to create a subclass of NSArray by using a pure is-a relationship, I guess, it would be kind of hard, as you would have to do C-level memory management.

But if you add a has-a relationship — or: create a wrapper — at the same time, you can the subcalssing quite easily: Just make your custom array class have a member of a regular NSArray. Now override its method by forwarding the calls to the member object. I showed this [in this post, where I just add objects, that pass a certain test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190530/does-objective-c-support-generics/8198852#8198852).

**But** you will see, that I didn't implement the method you talked about correctly, but I raise a error. The reason is: that method is a variadic methods, that has a variable number of objects you can pass in — and to handle this, you have to to a bit of work. [cocoawithlove has an great article about it.](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html)

For you — if using that has-a trick — it could look like

```
- (id) initWithObjects:(id)firstObj, ... {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        _realArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    }

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstObj);
    for (id obj = firstObj; obj != nil; obj = va_arg(args, id))
    {
        [self.realArray addObject:obj];
    }
    va_end(args);
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
self = [super initWithObjects:firstObj,nil];
```

Comment: you solved the delegate problem but there is still a warning of missing sentinel...

Comment: I tried `self = [super initWithObjects:firstObj, nil];` and warning disappeared, but will the object inside array missing when this subclass is called?

Comment: Yes, sorry you must add nil at the end. Sorry but I don't understand your question...

Comment: @BenLu: See jlehr's answer and my comment on it. That will work, but it will only (try to) initialize the array with the first object, not any others. At best, you will end up with an array containing no more than one object, regardless of how many objects were passed.

Comment: See my answer for a va_list-aware implementation.