# Type of class in a NSMutableArray

Tags: java, objective-c, class, arraylist, nsmutablearray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to enforce typing on NSArray, NSMutableArray, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649483/is-there-any-way-to-enforce-typing-on-nsarray-nsmutablearray-etc)

I'm Java programmer and I'm starting on Obj-C, in java i can create a mutable array with determined type of class, like as follow:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list;
```

in Obj-c I know the NSMutableArray but i don't know and not found how to determinate the type of class into it.

Have a way of make this with it or other class without NSMutableArray which can do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The questions you are asking is not clear. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: OP wants a parameterized array in Objectve C.

Comment: @crypticcoder ok, I'will do it.

Comment: That'd be *mutable* array, not *multable*.

Comment: this thread might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190530/does-objective-c-support-generics Note, that I posted 2 answers with the second one showing an approach, where the array can perform test prior to adding.

Comment: Objective-C does not support parameterized types directly. However you can code something close yourself, see [NSMutableArray - force the array to hold specific object type only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197446/nsmutablearray-force-the-array-to-hold-specific-object-type-only/5198040#5198040).

Comment: @vikingosegundo very cool, I'll test this, but probably i not go use in my project because i wanna use a native class.

Comment: I am not using it either in real world :) as I wrote in the first answer: if there is a need to limit the array to a certain type, most likely your architecture is buggy.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Good decision :), I have not yet tested it but seems like a good code, but it is better to adapt to the style of language to try to make it seem like the java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to enforce typing on NSArray, NSMutableArray, etc.?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/649483/), [NSMutableArray - force the array to hold specific object type only](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5197446/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Cocoa/Objective-C doesn't offer typed collections like this. All objects in the collection must inherit from `NSObject` (which is basically everything besides primitives and structs), but beyond that, it's up to you to understand/manage what is going on in the array. Objects in an `NSMutableArray` are represented in its interface by the generic type `id`.

---

From a design standpoint, collections in Cocoa typically do contain homogeneously-typed objects. The name of the array is often used to indicate what's inside it (just as in Java), e.g. `bookTitlesArray` or just `bookTitles` (i.e. strings). Additionally, from an abstraction standpoint, sometimes lightweight classes are used to "wrap" a raw `NSMutableArray` to enforce type checking at the interface. As in, a new class called `BookTitleList` which offered a subset of the add, lookup, remove methods and passed them through to an internal array after e.g. validation. But YMMV depending on your needs.

Comment: Understood, it seems necessary to understand a little better the architecture of Objectiv-c, will find a way to do it by the standards of language but I appreciate everyone's attention!

Answer (score 0):

Although there are no type parameters in Objective C, you'll find it much less of a nuisance than in Java because you don't have to downcast to call a method. Objective C is more like JavaScript in this respect.